# Rendered image is missing parts of the object that are visible in the 3D viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

My problem is that when I press ` + 1 to see the camera view in Viewport Display, I can see the spheres under my UFO.

Here is what it looks like :
[image]

But when I actually F12 and render, this is how it looks like :
[image]

As you can see, 2 of the 3 spheres that are visible on the first image are not visible on the render.
I don't understand why they look different when they are both camera views. I tried changing focal length but it doesn't seem to make any difference at all.

How can I sync two images exactly the same?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: are you sure you made them visible in the Outliner? (camera icon)

Comment: I swear to god I did that before uploading this question and it didnt work out, now I did it again and it worked! I feel so dumb

Comment: Thanks a lot :PP